# Sturm–Liouville problem with periodic conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Suppose I have the following Sturm–Liouville problem

$$\Theta''(\theta) + \lambda \Theta(\theta) = 0$$

with the following conditions

$$\space \Theta(\theta) = \Theta(\theta + 2\pi)  $$
$$\space \Theta'(\theta) = \Theta'(\theta + 2\pi)$$
I tried to solve it but I only found that if $\lambda = n^2 \neq 0$ then $\Theta(\theta) = Ae^{in\theta} + Be^{-in\theta}$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\Theta(\theta) = 1$ if $\lambda = 0$. How can I find the values of A and B?

Comment: They can be anything.   $e^{in\theta}$ and $e^{-in\theta}$ are eigenfunctions for this problem.

Comment: Why are they each an eigenfunction of this problem and not both together?

Comment: Any nonzero linear combination of them is also an eigenfunction.